# Sourcetree newer than 3.4.7 can't fetch/pull with a fatal protocol error: bad line length character

Tags: git, ssh, putty, atlassian-sourcetree, plink

I'm using Atlassian Sourcetree for Windows, and after a recent upgrade, it stopped working with some of my repositories.

The repositories are configured for passwordless access via SSH protocol (using public and private keys).

When I try to fetch or pull the repository, it shows the following error, where "xxxx" is the first 4 chars of my user name:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: xxxx
FATAL ERROR: Error reading from console: Error 109: The pipe has been ended.

Completed with errors, see above.
```

Before the upgrade, everything worked well.

I tested many versions (3.3.9, 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.4.4, 3.4.5, 3.4.6, 3.4.7) and found that the last working version is **3.4.7**, but more recent versions (3.4.8, 3.4.9, 3.4.10, 3.4.11, 3.4.12, 3.4.13 and 3.4.14) are broken in this respect.

What's wrong and how can I fix the error?

Answer (score 3):

The problem component, in my case, was **plink.exe** (part of Putty), bundled with Sourcetree.

Sourcetree 3.4.7 has plink.exe version **"0.70.2-sourcetree"** compiled specially for the Sourcetree project, but more recent versions have common plink.exe from [https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html).

The workaround is the following:

- Download Sourcetree for Windows 3.4.7 from the https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/download-archives
- Install it and copy file **plink.exe** from the program's directory: *C:\Users{yourname}\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-3.4.7\tools\putty\plink.exe* to a temporary place, for example, *C:\temp*
- Install the newest version of Sourcetree for Windows 3.4.14
- Replace *plink.exe* with the saved version of *plink.exe*
- Enjoy working latest Sourcetree

I hope the Sourcetree team will fix this bug in future releases.

Comment: After working on it for 40 hours, I noticed it initially occurred two years ago and I had to downgrade to 3.4.7 at that day.  Thank you for the solution. Sourcetree is a powerful tool, however, the development seems to attend the requests to well know git providers instead of custom repositories and servers. I had no trouble on MAC but, recently I had to move to windows as a backup, and lost track of time trying to solve the problem due to this ancient bug.

Comment: Alternative to install all of v3.4.7, you can also download the Enterprise for Windows v3.4.7 MSI package and unpack it with i.e. https://lessmsi.activescott.com, and copy that version of plink.exe to C:\Users{yourname}\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-{yourversion}\tools\putty\